# Why is the set composed of all intervals $(-r,r)$ for any rational number $r$, the empty set, and all real numbers not a topology?

Tags: general-topology

It seems like it ought to be:- $(-a,a) \cap (-b,b)$ where $a \leq b$ is $(-a,a)$ and $(-a,a) \cup (-b,b)$ is $(-b,b)$, so it should be closed under union and intersection. What am I missing?

Comment: Does the topology contain $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 7):

Topologies are closed under *arbitrary* unions. But if $q_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers converging monotonously from below to $\sqrt2$, then $\bigcup(-q_n,q_n)=(-\sqrt2,\sqrt2)$ which is not an interval with rational endpoints.